# Why is the C++ memory defined using a maximal sequence of bit-fields?

Tags: c++, memory

The smallest unit of storage is a byte, see [quotes from standard here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.memory):

> The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte.

But then a memory location is defined to possibly be adjacent bit-fields:

> A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having nonzero width.

I would like to understand this definition:

- If the smallest storage unit is a byte, why don't we define a memory location as a sequence of bytes?
- How do C-style bitfields fit with the first sentence at all?
- What is the point of *maximal sequence*; what is maximal here?
- If we have bitfields in the definition of memory, why do we need anything else? E.g. a float or int both are made up of bits, so the *'either an object of scalar type'*-part seems redundand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyze the terms:

For reference:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model

### Byte

As you said, smallest unit of (usually) 8 bits in memory, explicitly addressable using a memory address.

### Bit-Field

A sequence of *BITS* given with explicit bit count!

### Memory location

Every single address, of a byte-multiple type OR (!!!) the beginning of a contigious sequence of bit-fields of non-zero size.

### Your questions ##

Let's take the cpp-reference example with some more commments and answer your questions one by one:

```
struct S {
    char a;     // memory location #1, 8-bit character, no sequence, see missing :#, scalar-type.
    int b : 5;  // memory location #2, new sequence, new location, integer-type of 5-bits length
    int c : 11, // memory location #2 (continued) integer-type of 11-bits length
          : 0,  // (continued but ending!) IMPORTANT: zero-size-bitfield, sequence ends here!!!
        d : 8;  // memory location #3 integer-type 8-bit, starts a new bit-field sequence, thus, new memory-location
    struct {
        int ee : 8; // memory location #4
    } e;
} obj; // The object 'obj' consists of 4 separate memory locations
```

- If the smallest storage unit is a byte, why don't we define a memory location as a sequence of bytes?

*Maybe we want to have a fine-grained bit-level control of memory-consumption for given system-types, i.e. 7 bit integer, or 4 bit char, ...
A byte as the holy-grail of units would deny us that freedom*

- How do C-style bitfields fit with the first sentence at all?

*Actually, since the bit-field feature originates in C...
The important thing here is, even if you define a struct with bitfields, consuming for example only 11 bits, the first bit will be byte-aligned in the memory, i.e. will have a location aligned to 8-bit steps and the data-type will finally consume at least (!) 16 bits, to hold the bitfield...
The exact way to store the data is at least in C not standardized afaik.*

- What is the point of maximal sequence; what is maximal here?

*The point of maximal sequence is to allow efficient memory alignment of individual fields, compiler optimization, ... Maximal in this case means all bitfields declared in a sequences of size >= 1, i.e.  i.e. no other scalar types and no bitfield with ':0'*

- If we have bitfields in the definition of memory, why do we need anything else? E.g. a float or int both are made up of bits, so the 'either an object of scalar type'-part seems redundand.

*Nope, both are made up of bits, BUT: Not specifying the bit-size of the type, will make the compiler assume default size, i.e. int: 32-bit... If you don't need so much resolution of the integer value, but for example only 24bit, you write **unsigned int v : 24**, ...*

*Of course, the non-bitfield way to write stuff can be expressed with bitfields, e.g.:*

```
int a,
int b : 32 // should be equal to a
```

### BUT (something I don't know, any captain here?)

If the system defined default with of type T is n-bits and you write something like:

```
T value : m // m > n
```

I don't know what is the resulting behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

You can infer some of the reasons by looking at the statement that follows: " Two or more threads of execution can access **separate memory locations** without interfering with each other."

I.e. two threads cannot access **separate bytes** of an object. And two threads accessing adjacent bitfields may also interfere with each other.

The *maximal sequence* here is because the standard doesn't exactly specify how a sequence of bitfields is mapped to bytes, and which of those bytes can then be accessed independently. Implementations may vary in this respect. However, the *maximal sequence* of bitfields is the longest sequence that any implementation may allocate as a whole. In particular, a *maximal sequence* ends with a btfield of width 0. The next bitfield starts a new sequence.

And while integers and floats are made up of bits, "bitfield" in C and C++ refers specifically to 'object members of integral type, whose width in bits is explicitly specified.' Not everything made of bits is a bitfield.

Comment: Could I create larger ints with the bitfield notation, such as `int value : 128`?

Comment: @Beginner: Sort of. Yes, the declaration is valid, but no, it's still an `int` and thus restricted to values between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`.